# Distinct e group no MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tenho essa query:

```
db.getCollection('lojasDisponiveis').aggregate( [
  { $group: { _id:  { codigosLojas: "$codigosLojas", codigoUrl: "$codigoUrl" }}}
] );
```

**O problema:**

Pra cada loja ou grupo de lojas, eu tenho um código que vai em um parâmetro da url. Porém, algumas lojas tem urls diferentes (códigos diferentes) que trazem a mesma informação (as mesmas lojas (171 e 232).

```
 {
    "_id": {
        "codigosLojas": [
            171, 232
        ],
        "codigoUrl": 676
    }
 }, {
    "_id": {
        "codigosLojas": [
            171, 232
        ],
        "codigoUrl": 675
    }
 }, {
    "_id": {
        "codigosLojas": [
            10
        ],
        "codigoUrl": 11
    }
 }, {
    "_id": {
        "codigosLojas": [
            21
        ],
        "codigoUrl": 2
    }
 }
```

Nesse exemplo, as duas urls com códigos 676 e 675 trazem as mesmas informações. Preciso de apenas uma.

**O que preciso:**

Caso exista as mesmas lojas com códigosUrl diferentes, trazer apenas um conjunto de informações (de uma url apenas).
Por exemplo, esse retorno:

```
 { "_id" : { "codigosLojas" : [ 171, 232 ], "codigoUrl" : 675 } }
 { "_id" : { "codigosLojas" : [ 10 ], "codigoUrl" : 11 } }
 { "_id" : { "codigosLojas" : [ 21 ], "codigoUrl" : 2 } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode somente agrupar por `codigoUrl` que vai manter somente um documento:

```
db.getCollection('lojasDisponiveis').aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$codigoUrl",
        codigoUrl: { $first: "$codigoUrl" },
        codigosLojas: { $push: "$codigosLojas" }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Oi Lucas!! Editei a pergunta, não estava claro. Não seria apenas trazer um resultado de toda Collection, mas sim todos os resultados, no caso de lojas "duplicadas", trazer apenas um.